# Best practices to obtain peers from a torrent tracker?

Tags: bittorrent

Following the [bittorrent protocol](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP.2FHTTPS_Protocol) to write a bittorrent client and hit a wall: the announce request rarely returns with a single peer, and even that seems to ignore my handshake:

- using the latest official Ubuntu torrent file (tried server, desktop, LTS - all same experience)
- the first request to the announce URL comes back with a seemingly legit response, containing keys such as `interval`, `complete`, `incomplete` and `peers`
- under `peers` every 4-8 attempt I get a single peer IP/port, the rest of the time it's empty
- when initiating a [handshake](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Handshake) with the peer (using the `<pstrlen><pstr><reserved><info_hash><peer_id>` format), the socket connection (tried both TCP and UDP) can be established, writing the payload succeeds, but there is no response at all (not even with 3s TTL on it)

The torrent file - needless to say - works just fine with a proper torrent client, having many tens of peers at least.
My question is not to do a code review but rather if there is anything less known on what's a good practice on collecting reliable peers?

Should I poll the tracker for more peers and aggregate them through time? Is there a

Comment: "under peers every 4-8 attempt I get a single peer IP/port".  That's almost assuredly wrong.  Most attempts to this tracker return 50 peers, including a test just now.  The handshake is probably failing too.  The pattern you're following should work, but without details, we can only guess what's going wrong.

Comment: That's super helpful. It indicates my code is just incorrect - possibly in the payload when asking for peers. Thanks!

Comment: It seems there are a few dialects to communicate with the protocol and trackers/peers seem to vary in support. Switching to UDP (http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html) gave me better results on other torrents (eg Mint linux torrent).
I still don't know what protocol the official Ubuntu torrent would need. UDP is not replying for the connection request and the http tracker gives no peers: https://torrent.ubuntu.com/announce?info_hash=%3b%24%55%04%cf%5f%11%bb%db%e1%20%1c%ea%6a%6b%f4%5a%ee%1b%c0&left=3826831360&peer_id=M0-0-0--IT2022------&port=6881&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&compact=1

Comment: It gives me plenty of peers.  As a guess:  You're connecting via IPv4, so the tracker is filtering the peer list to IPv4 peers since you selected the compact representation.  No clue, otherwise.